# Flutter: Increasing output value by 1 – but only in the respective created widget

Tags: flutter, dart, variables, widget

I have the following requirement that i struggle with: how can I **increase** the text field in the card's **by 1**, but **only in the respective card in which the button is pressed** and not in all cards? with my current code, all cards are incorrectly increased by 1. *in the code I create only 3 cards for test purposes. the final app will have multiple.*

here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MainBlock(),
    );
  }
}

class MainBlock extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainBlockState createState() => _MainBlockState();
}

class _MainBlockState extends State<MainBlock> {
  int singleCounter = 0;

  void cardBrain() {
    singleCounter++;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: MyCard(
                myName: 'Card 01',
                singleCounter: singleCounter,
                button: () {
                  setState(() {
                    cardBrain();
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: MyCard(
                myName: 'Card 02',
                singleCounter: singleCounter,
                button: () {
                  setState(() {
                    cardBrain();
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: MyCard(
                myName: 'Card 03',
                singleCounter: singleCounter,
                button: () {
                  setState(() {
                    cardBrain();
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String myName;
  final int singleCounter;
  final Function button;

  MyCard({this.myName, this.singleCounter, this.button});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
      color: Color(0xFF4C93C7),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Text(
              singleCounter.toString(),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: button,
              child: Text(
                'Button $myName',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to control number from MainBlock? Is it mandatory to have callback function on `MyCard` .

Answer (score 0):

Make `MyCard` a `StatefulWidget` rather than `MainBlock` and keep the variable in the its respective `State`